# Assignment of a variable

Tags: python, variables, variable-assignment

I am puzzled with an issue of a variable assignment in python. I tried looking for [pages](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/variables.html) on internet about [this issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29), but I still do not understand it.

Let's say I assign a certain value to the variable:

```
v = 2
```

Python reserved a place in some memory location with a value `2`. We now know how to access that particular memory location by assigning to it a variable name: `v`

If then, we do this:

```
v = v + 4
```

A new memory location will be filed with the value `6` (2+4), so now to access this value, we are binding the variable `v` to it.

Is this correct, or completely incorrect?

And what happens with the initial value `2` in the memory location? It is no longer bound to any variable, so this value can not be accessed any more? Does this mean that in the next couple of minutes, this memory location will be freed by the garbage collector?

Thank you for the reply.

EDIT:

The `v = 2` and `v = v + 2` are just simple examples. In my case instead of 2 and v+2 I have a non-python native objects which can weight from tens of megabytes, up to 400 megabytes.
I apologize for not clearing this on the very start. I did not know there is a difference between integers and objects of other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, as far as this goes.  Actually, what happens is that Python constructs integer objects **2** and **4**.  In the first assignment, the interpreter makes **v** point to the **2** object.

In the second assignment, we construct an object **6** and make **v** point to that, as you suspected.

What happens next is dependent on the implementation.  Most interpreters and compilers that use objects for even atomic values, will recognize the **2** object as a small integer, likely to be used again, and very cheap to maintain -- so it won't get collected.  In general, a literal appearing in the code will not be turned over for garbage collection.

---

Thanks for updating the question.  Yes, your large object, with no references to it, is now available for GC.

Comment: what do you meant "most interpreters and compilers of this type"? the question is about Python in particular, which as far as i know doesn't have a garbage collector

Comment: Good point ... although garbage collection is up to the implementation.  We have one that does reclaim released memory; otherwise some of our big-data applications would fault.

Comment: Thank you @Prune and @maxymoo.
Why does wikipedia page about Assignment, state the following: ```assignment statement ... copies a value into the variable.```. Does assignment really copy the value into the variable? Or does it actually just point to that value (in the memory location)? These two are different things. Here is the link:
```https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29```

Comment: The Wikipedia page is generic to many programming languages.  In Python, the value copied is a pointer to **2**, rather than **2** itself.  This is a significant detail of the language definition.  In most languages, the actual value is copied to the variable's memory location.  The advantage for Python is that the size of *every* variable's primary location is one word of memory.

Comment: Thank you. So when Python copies a pointer to a certain object in memory location, the size of that object is irrelevant? It can be 1kb or 1gb, it's the same? The copying of the pointer will be "completed" with the equal speed?

Comment: Right: the *pointer* copy will be completed at a constant speed.  However, *building* the object is dependent upon the objects characteristics.  There's no magic here: if you make a trivial compute-and-copy alteration to each element of a 10,000-element array, you still pay the computation and space prices.

Answer (score 3):

The example with small integers (-5 to 256) is not the best one because these are represented in a special way (see [this](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/) for example).

You are generally correct about the flow of things, so if you had something like

```
v = f(v)
```

the following things happen:

- a new object gets created as a result of evaluating `f(v)` (modulo the small integer or literal optimization)
- this new object is bound to variable `v`
- whatever was previously in `v` is now inaccessible and, generally, may get garbage collected soon

Comment: Thank you @aldanor.
Is it a bad practice to use the ```v = v + someValue``` when there is no need for using it? For example, I can write this: ```v2 = v + someValue```. But from a perspective of a garbage collection, is it better if I assign the expression on the right side, to the previously defined variable (```v``` in this case), even though I do not have to do that?

Comment: It's not really a bad practice unless name shadowing introduces unnecessary confusion (e.g. assigning to the name that collides with function argument names). There would be no difference between these two examples in most cases since garbage collection doesn't happen instantly and, the chances are, by the time it does, `v` would be collected either way. I've never personally witnessed an example where this kind of thing would matter so unless you're working with humongous objects that are expensive to recycle you shouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: Understood. I thought that by introducing ```v = v +someValue``` I am saving the memory space somehow. As I see now that this is not the case, and as it may introduce the confusion, I will not use this kind of syntax.
Thank you for the help @aldanor.